# T-SQL DATEDIFF MONTH January

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff

This may seem like a very simple/silly question but, if I use this code on January, will the output be December (as in January - 1 = December)?

```
SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()));
```

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - Shorter answer; ***No.***  *(See the two answers below.)*

Comment: How about trying it? `declare @MyDate as Date = '20160115'; select @MyDate, DateName( Month, DateDiff( Month, -1, @MyDate ) );`. You can jiggle the date around and see what you get.

Comment: @MatBailie Holy smokes!

Comment: @MatBailie I get it now, he was using dateDIFF.  it was dateADD in my little head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using both functions incorrectly.  I recommend looking at the online help for more details, but here is an explanation of what you've done...

`DATEDIFF()`'s last two parameters are both `DATETIME`s.

- It finds the difference between those two dates.
- In years, or months, or days, or hours, etc.

So, when you supply a `-1` as the first date it is implicitly `CAST` to a `DATETIME`.

- As it happens, `0` is `1970-Jan-01 @ 00:00:00`
- Which means that `-1` is `1969-Dec-31 @ 00:00:00`.
- You did ***`How many months are there between 1969-Dec-31 and now?`***
- Which is current 1405 months

`DATENAME()`'s second parameter is also a `DATETIME`.

- It returns the name of the month for that date
- *Or name of day, etc.*

So, when you supplied `1405` as the `DATETIME` parameter, that also got implicitly converted.

- That's 1405 days after `1st Jan 1970`
- Which is `6th Nov 1973`
- So `DATENAME()` returns `'November'`

You possibly just want to take one month away from a specific date, and then get its name.

- `DATENAME( MONTH, DATEADD( MONTH, -1, getDate() ) )`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Now I understand the difference between DATEADD and DATEDIFF. I'll implement a DATEADD instead. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As written, no.  As of this current time, it will only return `November`.  This is because you're using `DATEDIFF` instead of `DATEADD`.

You can see a bit of why it does this by selecting the `DATEDIFF` portion:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, '2017-01-01')
```

> 1405

And `Select DateName(Month, 1405)` returns `November`.

But, this should be what you meant to use:

```
SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()));
```

And yes, using that will return `December`:

```
SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, '2017-01-01'));
```

> December